# Using single exe for different scheduled tasks

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

In current project, I'm using task scheduler to run a console application to perform some daily operations. Now, I am thinking to use the same console application for another operation that needed to be run every 15 minutes. To identify the operation in same console application, I'm planning to use different arguments. e.g.

```
MyProject.Services.exe "RunDailyTask"

MyProject.Services.exe "RunEvery15MinutesTask"
```

So, both schedulers will call the same exe but with different arguments to peform different operations.

My question is, will this be a good idea? Can one operation affect the other as both are sharing the same exe?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, will this be a good idea? Can one operation affect the
>   other as both are sharing the same exe?

No, Console exe is executed in separate process. when you run multiple instances of the same exe application each of these instances are executed in it's on process.

If an instance fails, only that process is affected; applications in other processes continue to perform. Of course, because memory addresses in one process have no meaning in another process

`You could simple test this by manually running two instances of your console application(by hard coding RunDailyTask and RunEvery15MinutesTask in each exe)`

Also instead of passing string arguments to console it would be preferable to use number flags(1,2) within the executable you could use enumerations with meaningful values if needed.

```
enum OperationType
{
  RunDailyTask = 1,
  RunEvery15MinutesTask = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes. good idea.
no. Can one operation affect the other as both are sharing the same exe?

windows run your applications by different instance (thread). of course you must be sure when RunEvery15MinutesTask must be finish its job before start RunDailyTask.

Comment: Thanks Nuri. In my case, RunDailyTask job is completely independent. So, for me it doesn't matter if it starts while RunEvery15MinutesTask is still running.

Comment: so you can use use same application.